# RXJS5 vs Promise.all

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

Is there an equivalent of a Promise.all?

```
let prom1 = doA(); // some promise
let prom2 = doB(); // another promise

// wait for both promises to complete.
Promise.all([prom1, prom2], values => {
    // do something;
});
```

Can't piece it together from the docs, various articles suggest ForkJoin, but can't get it working...

```
let behaviour1 = new BehaviourSubject(0);
let behaviour2 = new BehaviourSubject(1);
let allObserver = new ForkJoinObservable(behaviour1, behaviour2);

behaviour1.subscribe( () => console.log('i work'));
behaviour2.subscribe( () => console.log('i work'));
allObserver.subscribe( () => console.log('i dont work'));
```

Might just switch back to the sane world of promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rx.Observable` has a `toArray` function that can be used to replicate `Promise.all` behavior: it stores all of the stream's emitted values and waits for the underlying stream's onComplete event to fire. The resulting stream will emit a single item once all of the underlying items have been emitted:

```
// Instead of Promises, we can model our async actions as observables
const operation1$ = Rx.Observable.just(1);
const operation2$ = Rx.Observable.just(2);

// Merge all our async results into a single stream
const result$ = Rx.Observable.merge(operation1$, operation2$)

// Finally, call toArray to combine all results
result$
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// >> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

```
import Rx, { Observable } from 'rxjs' 
import axios from 'axios'

const promiseA = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    , promiseB = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2')

const promiseStream$ = Observable   
       .of(promiseA, promiseB)       // promises go here
       .flatMap(promise=>promise)    // resolve the promise under the hood         
       .map(response=>response.data)   
       .map(user=>user.name)   
       .subscribe(
           name=>console.log(`name is ${name}`)
           // name is Ervin Howell
           // name is Leanne Graham   
       )
```

> flatMap(promise=>promise) flapMap will help you to resolve promise under the hood

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat cheesy way of doing it is using `toPromise`

```
Promise.all([behaviour1.toPromise(), behaviour2.toPromise()])
```

`toPromise` will return a promise that resolves when the underlying observable completes.

However, since most observables emit more than 1 value before they complete, operations like `zip`, `combineLatest` and `withLatestFrom` might be closer to what you are looking for:

#### zip

Every value of behavior1 gets zipped with a value of behavior2.
If either input runs out of values, it stalls until that input has a value again.

```
Observable.zip(behavior1, behavior2)
  .subscribe(([b1, b2]) => console.log(b1, b2))
```

See also: [Docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip), 
[Interactive marble diagram](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip)

#### combineLatest

Like zip, but will emit a value every time either behavior1 or behavior2 emits a value, and will reuse the latest value of the other observable for the pairing.

```
Observable.combineLatest(behavior1, behavior2)
  .subscribe(([b1, b2]) => console.log(b1, b2))
```

See also: [Docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest),
[Interactive marble diagram](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest)

#### withLatestFrom

Like combineLatest, but only only one observable determines when a value gets emitted.

```
behavior1.withLatestFrom(behavior2)
  .subscribe(([b1, b2]) => console.log(b1, b2))
```

See also: [Docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom),
[Interactive marble diagram](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom)